# How to send values through an directive tag in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to send data through the directive metatags from one component to another but it shows error undefined when i consoled it.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

My component,

```
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<modal [hero]="value"></modal>'
})
export class CommonComponent  { 
  value : anny ='1';
```

}

```
@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  templateUrl : './modal/model.component.html'
})
export class CommonComponent  { 
  @Input() hero:any;
  consrtuctor(){
  console.log(this.hero) ///// shows o/p as undefined
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

In Angular, constructor is used for dependency injection. You need to call one of the built-in functions in component life-cycle when you want to deal with `@Input()` `@Output()` and similar decorators.

Instead of `constructor() {...}`, use:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.hero); // not undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is that at the point where your constructor is called, the @Input and @Output bindings haven't been set up yet by Angular. That's why your hero property is showing as undefined. If you want to make use of @Input and/or @Output bindings during the initialization of your component, you have to wait until Angular initializes those bindings first before trying to make use of them.

Angular provides a life cycle hook to accomplish this very same thing. Basically, if you define a method called ngOnInit on your component, after Angular has finished initializing your component, it will call that method. And at that point, your bindings will have the values you expect.

So, your class should be more like:

```
export class CommonComponent  { 
  @Input() hero:any;
  constructor(){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.hero) // will be defined at this point
  }
}
```

In general, you really should not have any real initialization logic in your constructor (because again, at the point your constructor is called, none of your bindings are in place). For the vast majority of components, your constructor is used solely to request service dependencies by listing those services as parameters to the constructor - initialization of the component happens in `ngOnInit`.

See the [lifecycle hooks guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) to learn more.